# How can I arrange this code so I can get different entry from database for each table row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, html-table

I want every different record of database to be display on each table rows, but I'm unable to retrieve different record for each row and column. Please give me suggestion where I can paste than while block so it will give different result for each row and column.

```
<?php
  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = '';
  $rec_limit = 10;
  $scriptname=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  if(! $conn )
  {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db('online_shopping');   // include your code to connect to DB.

 $tbl_name="mobile_db";     //your table name
 $start = 0;
 $limit = 5; 
 $sql = "SELECT id,company,model,price,availability,image FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start,  $limit";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            $company=$row['company'];
                            $model=$row['model'];
                            $available=$row['availability'];
                            $price=$row['price'];

                        }
 echo "<table border='2'>";
 $j = 0;
 for($j = 0; $j<5; $j++)
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++)
  {
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<table border='2'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='abc.jpg' height='250' width='250'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<table border='2'>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><b>Brand : </b></td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$company.'</td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><b>Model : </b></td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$model.'</td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><b>Availability : </b></td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$available.'</td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><b>Price : </b></td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$price.'</td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</td>";
    }
   echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Comment: 1. Move the start of your `<table>` to before your loop. 2. move the meaty part of your table output to INSIDE your `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){` loop.

Comment: i want to display records in a manner that used by most of the website to display number of items one after another, i am working on online shopping website so i want structure which will display in 3 columns and then it should break and move to next line and display another 3 columns and so on.. i want structure like this [link](http://www.snapdeal.com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones/filters/Form~Touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the table rows **inside** the fetch loop or store the row in an **array**. I have simplified your tables to make the example clearer:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
  /* Error */
}

echo '<table>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<tr><td><img src="', htmlspecialchars ($row['image']), '">';
  echo '<tr><td><table>';
  echo '  <tr><th>Brand<td>',        htmlspecialchars ($row['company']);
  echo '  <tr><th>Model<td>',        htmlspecialchars ($row['model']);
  echo '  <tr><th>Availability<td>', htmlspecialchars ($row['availability']);
  echo '  <tr><th>Price<td>',        htmlspecialchars ($row['price']);
  echo '  </table>';
}

echo "</table>\n";
```

Some notes about the code:

- Test the return value of `mysql_query()`. The query might fail.
- Escape your output using `htmlspecialchars()`.
- You should use `<th>` elements for your headings and style those, instead of using inline `<b>` elements.
- I added output of `$row['image']` which might not do what you want.
- And do **not** use the deprecated mysql extension. Use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` loop you always rewrite the same variables, after loop you have only last record saved.

In the loop, you have to save records into array.

In your code you have nested tables, but in the first one, there is only one row and one table cell which contains another table. I use just nested table.

```
<?php

...
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

if (count($data) > 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>Brand: ' . $row['company'];
            echo '<td>Model: ' . $row['model'];
            echo '<td>Availability: ' . $row['availability'];
            echo '<td>Price: ' . $row['price'];
    }
    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo 'no records';
}

?>
```

Comment: can i use this code to solve this problem of over writting the same data again and again

Comment: Sure, you could try it. In this code you overwrite nothing, just create an array `data` and loop this array in one `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but try this.

```
<?php
  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = '';
  $rec_limit = 10;
  $scriptname=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  if(! $conn )
  {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db('online_shopping');   // include your code to connect to DB.

 $tbl_name="mobile_db";     //your table name
 $start = 0;
 $limit = 5; 
 $sql = "SELECT id,company,model,price,availability,image FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start,  $limit";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

  echo "<table border='2'>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo  "<td>".$row['company']."</td>";
                            echo  "<td>".$row['model']."</td>";
                            echo  "<td>".$row['availability']."</td>";
                            echo  "<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```